# The curl of magnetic field is coming out to 0

Tags: magnetic-fields, vector-fields

This question is a continuation of my [previous post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327635/proof-divergence-of-magnetic-field-is-0). Using this [magnetic field equation](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~acosta/phy2061/lectures/MagneticDipoles.pdf) in vector polar coordinates, I was curious to test Maxwell's equation $$\bigtriangledown \times \vec{B} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} + \vec{J} \, .$$

The polar coordinates of the magnetic field with respect to $|r|$ is

$$
\vec{B} = \left ( 2 |u| \frac{\mu \cos \theta}{4 \pi |\vec{R}|^3}\right )\hat{r} + \left (|u| \frac{\mu \sin \theta}{4 \pi |\vec{R}|^3}\right )\hat{\theta} + 0\hat{\phi} \, .
$$

However, when I take the $\bigtriangledown \times B$ I get zero.

Here are my steps:

In polar coordinates

$$
\bigtriangledown \times \vec{B}  = 
\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}B_\phi \sin\theta - \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}B_\theta  \right]\hat{r} + 
\frac{1}{r}\left[ \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}B_r - \frac{\partial}{\partial r}rB_\phi  \right]\hat{\theta} + 
\frac{1}{r}\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}rB_\theta - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}rB_r  \right]\hat{\phi} \, .
$$

Luckily the magnetic field vector, $\hat{\phi} =0$ which simplifies our equation to

$$
\bigtriangledown \times \vec{B}  =
\frac{1}{r}\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}rB_\theta - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}rB_r  \right]\hat{\phi} \, .
$$

Solving for the partial derivatives inside the brackets leave me with

$$
\bigtriangledown \times \vec{B}  = \frac{1}{|R|}\left[ -\frac{\mu_o|u|\sin\theta}{2 \pi|R|^3} +\frac{\mu_o|u|\sin\theta}{2 \pi|R|^3}\right]= 0 \, .
$$

I can't even continue with this equation, because it's simply zero.
This doesn't make sense to me. Can someone please explain how I obtained zero? I understand putting those vector components through $\bigtriangledown \cdot \vec{B}$ gives me 0, but not this.

Comment: @garyp The vector component $\hat{\phi}$ is zero in a polar coordinates simply because the magnetic field does not change with respect to $\hat{\phi}$, equi-potential lines. Therefore anything in the original polar curl definition that contains $\hat{\phi}$ is 0, leaving you with the 'simplified'.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out and deleted my comment.   Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Also to comment on your first comment. I care only about values $R>0$

Comment: In the region where you're calculating the field, the current is zero, so it makes sense that the curl should be zero. Similarly, the electric field of a point charge has zero divergence for $r \neq 0$, even though there is charge density somewhere. The magnetic field diverges at the point where the current is nonzero, so you have to make a more careful calculation.